# strapi error when i open settings or content-type-builder

Tags: strapi

My strapi project is working on local and i am able to open the urls
with out any error

```
http://localhost:1337/admin/settings/application-infos
http://localhost:1337/admin/plugins/content-type-builder/content-types/api::account-cms.account-cms
```

but when i push and deploy on heroku i am getting below error

```
13react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined
    at defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at ye (7909.4877546f.chunk.js:504:1387)
    at ss (main.1de49b44.js:48:54759)
    at h4 (main.1de49b44.js:52:9145)
    at bd (main.1de49b44.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.1de49b44.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.1de49b44.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.1de49b44.js:50:11072)
    at main.1de49b44.js:48:39565
    at f.unstable_runWithPriority (main.1de49b44.js:84:3950)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367
7909.4877546f.chunk.js:504
```

I tried to purge cache and updated yarn.lock and deployed many times but i am getting same error. i am connected to same database

Comment: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/configurations prolly you miss some config…